# how to enter time-stamps in mysql from an input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp

I need to insert Timestamp in MySQL from input in  Laravel application

data coming from my input is in this format `12/27/2017`  `MM/DD/YYYY` how can I convert it into this format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

any alternatives are highly appreciated like pass data from the input which input we use so, I can get data in `timestamp` format.

and at the end, I need to sort data `order by date`

Comment: Your input data has no time part. So what time do you want to be in the result?

Comment: time can be 00-00-00

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it in Laravel way you can use [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) and [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). This is an example of model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

class Post extends Model {

    protected $dates = ['date'];


    public function setDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value);
    }
}
```

Now when you update or create post `date` attribute will be automatically converted. So you can save it like this:

```
$post = new Post(); 
$post->date = '16/12/2017';
$post->save();
```

Comment: i need to convert this formate 'd/m/Y' to timestamp formate to to create a custom 'd/m/Y' formate that i can insert into database

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime:

```
$inputDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '12/27/2017');
$formatedDate = $inputDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: You are using `$inputDate` and `$date`. It should be the same variable.

Comment: what if we are using mass assignment and need to done this work in models using mutators in laravel way ?

Comment: This was not in the question, but if you want that, use Andriy's answer and combine with my answer. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As for me I done date conversion in this way, for example to making invoices. I hope this can be done by PHP.

```
$input_date = "12/15/2017"; // input in MM/DD/YYYY
$output_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($input_date)); //set output to 2017-12-15 00:00:00
echo $output_date; //produce output
```

It generates the following result

```
2017-12-15 00:00:00
```

I hope this will work. If you want only date, you can omit H:i:s based on your purpose. Thank you.

Comment: it worked fine but i am looking to laravel way of doing this in model

Answer (score 0):

```
$date=date_create("12/27/2017");
$rawDate =  date_format($date,"Y/m/d");// Produced - 2017/12/27
echo  str_replace('/','-',$rawDate ); // Output - 2017-12-27
```

- to add `H:i:s`, if there is no time just add 00:00:00 at the end of date begins with space.
- **If you're dealing with `created_at` or `updated_at` which Laravel create for every table, you must add `00:00:00` to end of date to get all data begins with that respective date**

Comment: I had to edit this and another of your answers. You know what blockquotes are for, so please don't use them for this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me if we want the format of date from input is different from the format the timestamp accepts

Laravel way of doing is

```
  protected $fillable = ['organization_name', 'job_apply_link', 'job_description', 'city_id', 'province_id', 'sector_id', 'image_file', 'test_id', 'newspaper_id', 'catagory_id', 'slug', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_description', 'job_title', 'created_at'];  

 public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $inputDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value);
        $formatedDate = $inputDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->attributes['created_at'] = $formatedDate;

    }
```